# Flappy bird game with AI - Genetics algorithm doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, neural-network, p5.js, genetic-algorithm

I have a flappy bird game built with p5.js, every bird in my game is a neural network with 4 inputs, 4 hidden nodes, and 1 output.
if the output is bigger than 0.5, the bird should jump.

I use the genetics algorithm to improve the neural network, and I *mostly* select the neural networks(birds) with the best weights and biases, which are determined by the fitness score, crossover the parents, mutate by a low rate, and pass the offspring on to the next generation.

So for total of 10 birds, in the next generation, there should be 10 offspring that are somewhat better than the last 10 birds' generation.

After printing the fitness scores of my birds, seems like even after 300 generations, there is no improvement in the fitness score of each individual bird.
The way I calculate fitness is by the score itself, the score is incrementing every frame for each bird, and the longer the bird stays alive, the higher the score is.

My first approach was to look for anything that could overwrite the next generation with a brand new array of birds, but I couldn't spot anything that does it.

**nextGeneration():**

```
 const nextGeneration = () => {
  calculateFitness();
  for (let i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++) {
    // Select the most fit bird
    let bird1 = rouletteWheelSelection();
    print("Bird 1: " + bird1.fitness)
    // Select another most fit bird
    let bird2 = rouletteWheelSelection();
    print("Bird 2: " + bird2.fitness)
    // Use the crossover function to create an offspring from bird1 and bird2
    let offspringBrain = crossOver(bird1, bird2);
    // Mutate the offspring's brain with a small probability
    offspringBrain.mutate(0.1);
    // Add the offspring to the new population of birds
    birds[i] = new Bird(offspringBrain);
  }
  // Clear the saved birds for the next generation
  savedBirds = [];
}
```

**rouletteWheelSelection():**

```
const rouletteWheelSelection = () => {
  //Sum of total fitness
  let totalFitness = 0
  savedBirds.forEach( element => {
      totalFitness += element.fitness
  });

  // Generate a random number between 0 and the total fitness
  const rand = Math.random() * totalFitness;

  // Select the chromosome with the corresponding fitness
  let fitnessSum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < savedBirds.length; i++) {
    fitnessSum += savedBirds[i].fitness;
      if (fitnessSum >= rand) return savedBirds[i];
  }
}
```

**crossOver():**

```
const crossOver = (bird1, bird2) => {
  // Create a new NeuralNetwork by cloning bird1's brain
  let offspring = bird1.brain.copy()

  // Select a random point to split the weights and biases
  let splitPoint = Math.floor(Math.random() * offspring.weights_ih.data.length);

  // Cross over the weights and biases of bird1 and bird2 at the split point
  for (let i = splitPoint; i < offspring.weights_ih.data.length; i++) {
    offspring.weights_ih.data[i] = bird2.brain.weights_ih.data[i];
    offspring.weights_ho.data[i] = bird2.brain.weights_ho.data[i];
    offspring.bias_h.data[i] = bird2.brain.bias_h.data[i];
    offspring.bias_o.data[i] = bird2.brain.bias_o.data[i];
  }

  return offspring;
}
```

**draw() in the main sketch.js file:**

```
function draw() {
  if (counter % 150 == 0) {
  pipes.push(new Pipe());
  }
  counter++;
  for (var i = pipes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    pipes[i].update();

    for (let j = birds.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

      if (pipes[i].hits(birds[j])) {
        savedBirds.push(birds.splice(j, 1)[0]);
      }

      if (pipes[i].offscreen()) {
        pipes.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  for (let bird of birds) {
    bird.think(pipes);
    bird.update();
  }
  if (birds.length == 0 ) {
    counter = 0;
    nextGeneration();
    pipes = [];
  }
  background(bgImg);
  for (let bird of birds) {
    bird.show();
  }
  for (let pipe of pipes) {
    pipe.show();
  }
}
```

Another approach I had in mind, was to look at the game side itself, and see if there's any issue in the way that the birds try to predict the output, but it does seem like the input nodes are correct.

**think() in Bird.js**:

```
   think(pipes) {
    //Find closest pipe
    let closest = null;
    let closestD = Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++) {
        let d = pipes[i].x - this.x;
        if (d < closestD && d > 0) {
         closest = pipes[i];
         closestD = d;
        }
    }
    let inputs = [];
    inputs[0] = this.y / height; // bird's y
    inputs[1] = closest.top / height; // top pipe's y
    inputs[2] = closest.bottom / height; // bottom pipe's y
    inputs[3] = closest.x / width;  // pipes' x
    let output = this.brain.predict(inputs); // predict if bird should jump 
    if (output[0] > 0.5) {
      this.up()
    } 
  }
```

What am I missing?